# Collapse only on Mobile View Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the desktop view the "ul .item-description" should be visible, but on the mobile view it should be collapsed. I did it but it seems to me that this is a terrible decision. How can I improve this? Also, the arrow does not work the first time. How to fix it? I tried to fix this with js, but when I refresh the page I see how the arrow is twitching.

Sorry, my english is very bad.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p6t3brob/13/

html

```
<div class="collapsed-item">
  <div class="collapse-element-title visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#items">collapse-title

  </div>

  <ul class="item-description hidden-xs" id="items">
    <li class="title">title-text</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.collapsed-item {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.collapse-element-title {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.collapse-element-title:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  content: "";
}

.collapse-element-title.collapsed:after {
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.collapse-element-title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.collapse-element-title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  #items.in,
  #items.collapsing {
    display: block!important;
  } 
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  #crownDesc.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this http://jsfiddle.net/p6t3brob/15/

```
<div class="collapsed-item">
  <div class="collapse-element-title visible-xs collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#items">collapse-title

  </div>

  <ul class="item-description hidden-xs collapse" id="items">
    <li class="title">title-text</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
    <li>item-item-item......</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```